# Overriding Shipping Charge without creating a new Order

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, order-duplication

There is an admin override for a shipping price available in Magento.

The issue is that in order to do this the order is duplicated and the information on shipping address and billing address doesn't translate over to the new order, so it is generally a pain.

Is there a way to provide the custom shipping rate on an order without having to "Edit" it and going through reduced order creation process?

Answer (score 2):

This extension overwrites all shipping rates and you can create rules easly.
http://amasty.com/shipping-rules.html

Answer (score 1):

A fantastic paid extension to consider is Mageworx's [Extended Orders](http://www.mageworx.com/extended-orders-magento-extension.html) extension. Not being able to edit an order without cancelling it is a serious oversight by Magento. I have paid more for another company's extension to allow order editing, but the Mageworx has more features and is IMHO a well constructed extension with comprehensive overloading of the core features in the orders process.